# How to keep a user process running until Windows logoff is definite?

Tags: windows, winapi

I have an application that is running on Windows, in the user's session, that I don't want the user to be able to close by accident.

One way the user can close it is by having unsaved data (e.g. in notepad) and start the process of logging off. Notepad rejects the WM_QUERYSESSION message; Windows prompts the user that there is unsaved data; and the user gets to cancel the logoff.

Other applications (including mine), get the WM_QUERYSESSION, respond with TRUE, then get WM_ENDSESSION, and quit. Importantly, they quit before Windows has even decided to prompt the user about unsaved data in notepad.

If the user cancels the logoff, the end result is that the user's session continues without all the processes that honoured the end session messages.

What I'm trying to find a way of doing is keeping my process running until we're past the point that the user could cancel the logoff. Looking at the microsoft docs on this, I don't see an obvious way of doing that - each process goes through its own WM_QUERYSESSION > WM_ENDSESSION, and the docs are explicit that this happens for each application independently.

I don't want to reply to WM_QUERYSESSION with FALSE, as I don't want to block the logoff myself, just stay running if something else blocks it.

Are there any other ways of finding out when Windows has decided that all the WM_QUERYSESSION messages were replied to with TRUE, and the logoff is inevitable?

(I think this is a Windows question, rather than a question specific to the language I'm using, but in case it matters, it's PureBasic. Any Win32 API approach should be workable though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any app returns FALSE to `WM_QUERYENDSESSION`, apps that had already returned TRUE will receive `WM_ENDSESSION` with `wParam=FALSE` to indicate shutdown has been canceled.

If all apps return TRUE to `WM_QUERYENDSESSION`, only then will they receive `WM_ENDSESSION` with `wParam=TRUE` to indicate shutdown is proceeding.

See [Application Shutdown Changes in Windows Vista](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms700677(v=vs.85)) and [Restart Manager: Guidelines for Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/rstmgr/guidelines-for-applications) for more details of how `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` and `WM_ENDSESSION` work.

Is your app paying attention to the `wParam` value given by `WM_ENDSESSION`? Or does it just blindly exit unconditionally when it receives `WM_ENDSESSION`?  Not all apps pay attention like they should be.  Make sure yours does.

---

**Update**: Per the [`WM_QUERYENDSESSION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shutdown/wm-queryendsession) documentation, and the [`Logging Off`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shutdown/logging-off) documentation:

> When an application returns TRUE for `WM_QUERYENDSESSION`, it receives the `WM_ENDSESSION` message and it is terminated, **regardless of how the other applications respond to the `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` message.**

So, there is really nothing your app can do here.  Once it responds `TRUE` to `WM_QUERYENDSESSION`, that is it, game over.  Your app will receive `WM_ENDSESSION` and be forcibly terminated if it does not exit within a few seconds, regardless of how other apps respond to the shutdown.

So, the only way I can think of to really detect when the session is actually ending is to use a service instead, as a service can receive `SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN` and `SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE` notifications.

Comment: Yes, I am paying attention to that. The problem is that I receive a WM_ENDSESSION with wParam TRUE straightaway, i.e. several seconds before the user even sees the prompt that allows them to cancel the log off (never mind how long it is until they click the cancel button)

Comment: That is not documented behavior

Comment: I have a service as well - but that's not running in the user session, and can't display windows to the user, or relaunch the user piece. As far as the messages are concerned, I'd reached much the same conclusion as above - that it is game over at that point - but thought I'd ask here for 2 reasons. 1; Not all windows processes exit (e.g. explorer itself doesn't), so there must be some (undocumented?) way to stay around during logoff, and 2; given this behaviour, what is the wParam on WM_ENDSESSION for? The timings are such that you would never receive it with wParam FALSE.

Comment: "*I have a service as well - but that's not running in the user session*" - no, but it can detect when the user's session is running, and then act accordingly. "*and can't display windows to the user*" - actually, it can, using `WTSSendMessage()` for simple popup messages, or `CreateProcessAsUser()` to launch a UI app in the user' session. "*or relaunch the user piece*" - again, `CreateProcessAsUser()`. "*Not all windows processes exit (e.g. explorer itself doesn't)*" - Explorer is the default user shell, so it won't be terminated until the session ends.

Comment: CreateProcessAsUser() looks like the right answer in this case - I wasn't aware you could do this kind of thing without knowing the user's password. Thanks for the help!